# com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.9 09/02/2011 11:17 AM'

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, tomcat9

22-Sep-2020 09:34:49.138 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-5] com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init No provider classes found.
22-Sep-2020 09:34:49.142 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-5] com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.9 09/02/2011 11:17 AM'
22-Sep-2020 09:34:49.484 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public javax.ws.rs.core.Response

I am also receiving same error, strange here is, application is working on local tomcat 9 but it's not working on tomcat 9 which has installed on ubuntu.
The difference observed that, on local jersey version 'jersey : 1.18' but on ubuntu jersey version taking as 'jersey:1.9', where could I find the jersey version ? I just simply generating .war file and copying on webapps folder in tomcat.

Please advise what dependencies or what went wrong here..

Comment: Please provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example or add more detailed code snippets on what you have tried. Thank you.

Comment: I have searched a lot in google and whatever suggestions to add jar's were already been added into application. here is pom.xml file looks ilke

Comment: <dependency><groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId><artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId><version>1.9</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId><artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId><version>1.9</version></dependency>
<dependency><groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId><artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId><version>1.19</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId><artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId><version>1.17.1</version></dependency>

Comment: <dependency><groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId><artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId><version>1.18</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId><artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId><version>1.13</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId><artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId><version>1.18</version></dependency>

Comment: I have provided my dependencies which I am using for Jersey servlet.. Please let me know what was wrong here.